# How to get CPU usage in percentages

Tags: cpu-load

At the moment I am using a `python` script to log the output from `cat /proc/loadavg` to a file. I then use `gnuplot` to periodically graph the CPU load for my viewing pleasure.

However, I really would like to have a graph that shows percentages of CPU usage (%user and %sys, etc.) instead. I can see that `top` can get to those numbers, since they are displayed at the third line of its output. However, I have not been able to figure out how or where `top` gets that information. Google is no help either, it just points me to either `/proc/loadavg` or problems people are having with high CPU loads.

Any hints on how I would be able to log those numbers (preferably as 5-minutes averages) to a file would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html

Comment: @Flint : Yes. I have `sysstat` installed. I can only get `sar` to hand me 10 minute averages. And `mpstat`s numbers don't compare with those from `top`.

Comment: @Flint : Mmm, they **do** add up better than `top`, but `mpstat` is a bit of a strain on an embed system. Let me look into that further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM: The manpage for `top` is a long read but eventually things became clear.

I'm now using this:

```
top -bn 1 |grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print "user: " $2+$6 "% syst: " $4+$12+$14+$16 "% wait: " $10 "% idle: "$8"%   Total: " $2+$4+$6+$8+$10+$12+$14+$16 "%"}'
```

Unfortunately it hardly ever perfectly totals at 100%

```
@boson:~ $ top -bn 1 |grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print "user: " $2+$6 "% syst: " $4+$12+$14+$16 "% wait: " $10 "% idle: "$8"%   Total: " $2+$4+$6+$8+$10+$12+$14+$16 "%"}'
user: 1.2% syst: 0.7% wait: 0.8% idle: 97.4%   Total: 100.1%
@boson:~ $
```

An alternative would be to install the `sysstat` package and use `mpstat` thusly:

```
@boson:~ $ mpstat | tail -1 | awk {'print "user: " $4+$5 "% syst: " $6+$8+$9+$10+$11+$12 "% wait: " $7 "% idle: " $13 "%   Total: " $4+$5+$6+$7+$8+$9+$10+$11+$12+$13 "%"}'
user: 1.18% syst: 0.66% wait: 0.76% idle: 97.39%   Total: 99.99%
@boson:~ $
```